# How to add a label when hovering the x in an input of type search html, CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an input of type search,

Currently, in the CSS I am able to customize it's color by applying a filter.

I am also able to make hovering on the x work to change the color.

Now, my problem is, that when hovering that x, I want to add a message near the x saying "Clear" for accessibility reasons.

What I am finding weird is even when I've added a span under of class accessibility-label I am unable to target it.

Should potentially change the background color to red, but it's not doing anything.

So I am looking for a way to add a popover message when hovering the x of an input of type search.

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button:hover .accessibility-label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />
<span class="accessibility-label"> Clear </span>
```

Comment: Input elements don’t have children so I don’t see how you can target that way. Please show the relevant HTML. Where has the label come from?

Comment: @AHaworth Hello, i added a span under the input, i am juste trying for now to try to edit the span when the x is hovered, just to see if i can access it like that. But if theres a better way to add a popover message the x, go for it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What "x" are you talking about?

Comment: @DanielBeck inside the input, when you type, an x appear to clear the input. When i hover it, i want to add a clear label to tell the user that this cears the input

Comment: Ah, I see.   Styling nonstandard shadow dom elements is a crapshoot; for what it's worth your color changes aren't working for me either (osx, both safari and chrome).  The only rule I can get that shadow element to respect is "display:none"

Comment: Note that this is going to be Chromium-specific as that's the only browser engine that shows an X when start typing content in. Firefox (and possibly Safari) does not.

Comment: (Safari does show it.  Safari and Opera use webkit; chromium was a long-ago webkit fork but still respects (some?) webkit rules)

Comment: @TylerH i see it on edge also

Comment: @codecodecode Edge uses Chromium as its rendering engine.